# BigQuery Order By one financial year(52 weeks)

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-order-by

I have this dataset right now.

| Date | Sales | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-02 | xxxxxxxx | A |
| 2022-11-03 | xxxxxx | A |
| 2022-11-03 | xxxxxx | B |
| 2021-11-03 | xxxxxx | A |
| 2021-11-04 | xxxxxx | B |
| 2021-11-04 | xxxxxx | A |

I want to order my data as this, where it will order the date by one year

| Date | Sales | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-02 | xxxxxxxx | A |
| 2021-11-03 | xxxxxx | A |
| 2022-11-03 | xxxxxx | A |
| 2021-11-04 | xxxxxx | A |
| 2022-11-03 | xxxxxx | B |
| 2021-11-04 | xxxxxx | B |

(because they have 52 weeks of interval)

Is there a possible way to do it?

I want to avoid join!
Sorry just to make it clear, I need to make sure that the the first row['date'] and second row['date'] has exactly 52 weeks of interval
i.e. date_sub(second_row['date'],interval 52 week) == first row['date']

Really sorry for the confusing

Comment: *order by Group, Date desc* is not enough ?

Comment: No, I have a large dataset and I want to make sure that the interval of the date is exactly one year

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, then what if Group 'A' has Date '2022-09-15'  without it's pair '2021-09-15' ?  and considering only year '2022' and '2021' ?

Comment: For the first case, I need to keep the data.

Comment: And the year is not only for 2022 and 2021, but the interval is always going to be a year.

Comment: then how about *ORDER BY \`Group\`, FORMAT_DATE('%m%d', Date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) DESC* ?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Because by doing that the first row's date and the second row's date won't have interval with 1 year

Comment: Have you tried it on the sample data ? Above *order by* shows exact same result as your expected output.

Comment: The real data I get is much more complicated than this one. I have two years of continuous data (2021-2022) where I want to order like 2021-1-1,2022-1-1;2021-1-2, 2022-1-2......2021-10-03, 2022-10-03 ......

Comment: I know your real dataset is much more complicated than this, that's why I try to get more information from you about your dataset.  My question was to check if my suggestion works for the sample data you provided at least.

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion. This is what I really want to achieve date_sub(second_row['date'],interval 52 week) == first row['date']

Comment: I tried to use your way and it is working with my first explanation, I didn't realize until I scrow down the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below instead of previous answer.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
    SELECT DATE '2022-11-02' Date, 'xxxxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-11-03' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-11-03' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'B' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-03' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-04' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'B' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-04' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group`
)
SELECT *
  FROM sample_data
 ORDER BY `Group`,
       EXTRACT(WEEK FROM Date) || EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM Date),
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) DESC;
```

###### Query results:

[image]

Comment: Really thank you for your reply. But when I try to apply same methodology into my database. It does not work. Also what I really want to achieve is that the 'Date' in second row has exactly one year interval with the first row(i.e.date_sub(second_row['date'], interval 1 year) == first_row['date'] (either way is fine).

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation

Comment: @Skylar, I've updated the answer. so kindly check that again. But you should note that a  leap year can have 53 weeks and in case, above logic might not work for days in 53th week.

Comment: Thank you so much, will have a look

Comment: WITH sample_data AS (
    SELECT DATE '2021-12-31' Date, 'xxxxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-12-31' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-01-01' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'B' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-01-01' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-01-02' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'B' `Group` UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-12-30' Date, 'xxxxxx' Sales, 'A' `Group`
)
SELECT *  FROM sample_data
 ORDER BY `Group`,
       EXTRACT(WEEK FROM Date) || EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM Date),
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) DESC;

Comment: When I tried to use this for 12-31, it is not really working

Comment: @Skylar,  would you show data you tested ?  above query has only days in 2021 and I can't see their 52 weeks layter days.